# Joining multiple line items into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL query that can combine multiple line items from one table into one line item.
I have two tables:

```
    Table: results     ||    Table: conditions
    ---------------    ||    ----------------------------------
    | id  | value |    ||    | id  | result_id | name | value |
    ---------------    ||    ----------------------------------
    |  1  | 5.2   |    ||    |  1  |       1   | temp |   5   |
    |  2  | 9.9   |    ||    |  2  |       1   | wave | 100   |
    |  3  | 12.1  |    ||    |  3  |       2   | temp |   5   |
    |  4  | 6.6   |    ||    |  4  |       2   | wave | 200   |
    |     |       |    ||    |  5  |       3   | temp |  25   |
    |     |       |    ||    |  6  |       3   | wave | 100   |
    |     |       |    ||    |  7  |       4   | temp |  25   |
    |     |       |    ||    |  8  |       4   | wave | 200   |
    ---------------    ||    ----------------------------------
```

The conditions table has many more different conditions than shown, but in this case I only care about `wave`and `temp`.

I'd like to make a query that lets me select certain results/conditions, resulting in something like:

```
-----------------------------------
| result_id | temp | wave | value |
-----------------------------------
|       1   |   5  | 100  |   5.2 |
|       4   |  25  | 200  |   6.6 |
-----------------------------------
```

or (by condition temp = 5)

```
-----------------------------------
| result_id | temp | wave | value |
-----------------------------------
|       1   |   5  | 100  |   5.2 |
|       2   |   5  | 200  |   9.9 |
-----------------------------------
```

So far, I've managed to filter for one condition using:

```sql
SELECT conditions.result_id, conditions.name, conditions.value, results.value
FROM conditions
INNER JOIN results ON results.id = conditions.result_id
WHERE (results.id = 1 OR results.id = 4)
AND conditions.name LIKE "temp";
-- WHERE conditions.name LIKE "temp" AND conditions.value = 5
```

But I don't know how to also search for `wave` that matches the same `result_id` and put it on the same line.

Comment: researh mysql pivot and mysql conditional aggregation and mysql prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use condition aggregate function. `case when` with `max` function.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT results.id, 
       MAX(case when conditions.name = 'temp' then conditions.value end)temp, 
       MAX(case when conditions.name = 'wave' then conditions.value end)wave, 
       results.value
FROM conditions
INNER JOIN results ON results.id = conditions.result_id
WHERE (results.id = 1 OR results.id = 4)
GROUP BY results.id,results.value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7243fa/2/0)**:

```
| id | temp | wave | value |
|----|------|------|-------|
|  1 |    5 |  100 |   5.2 |
|  4 |   25 |  200 |   6.6 |
```

Comment: what if I wanted to filter for temp = 5 instead of by id?

Comment: That looks like it just forces id 1 & 4 to have a temp of 5. I'm asking how to search for ids that have a temp of 5 and display them in the aggregated form, similar to the last table of my edited question.